# Создать батник с помощью командной строки

Tags: cmd

Нужно создать батник который который будет постранично выводить содержимое файлов с расширением *.log и файлов с расширением *.txt
Пытался таким способом, но *.txt файлы не отображаются:

```
@echo off
setlocal
more *.log /E
pause
more *.txt /E
pause
```

Помогите, пожалуйста)

Comment: `type file.txt`?

Comment: Нет, нужно чтоб выводилась информация всех *.log и *.txt файлов с диска С.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, ответ был прост. type filename.txt | more